# Why have most REP token transfers been failing?

Tags: tokens, augur

Almost all REP transfer attempts have been failing recently:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x48c80F1f4D53D5951e5D5438B54Cba84f29F32a5

This seems to have started about a month ago. Poloniex, Kraken and a few other have been submitting successful transactions, while others have mostly failed.

Any idea why?